# Order of the items in returned List from File.ReadAll()

Tags: c#, data-structures, collections

I am not too sure of what the answer to this is so I would appreciate information to help me better understand what I have here. My goal is to read the contents of a text file into a list, parse the information and remove orphan records(child records/line that do not have associated parent records/line before it in the file) and then write the remaining lines back to the file in order.

I use the following approach

```
IList<String> lines  = File.ReadAll(Filepath);
IList<String> secondlines = lines.Copy();

foreach (String line in lines) 
{
    If Brecord 
        foreach String record in secondlines 
        {
             if  record is same as Brecord 
                   //No Parent record found for this Brecord before it
                    Delete record 
              else if record is Parent of Brecord 
                     exit loop
         }
}


File.WriteAll(secondlines , SecondPath)
```

How can I make sure that everytime this happens, the contents of the file are handled in the order they appear in the file please?

Comment: Is your code not currently writing the lines in the same order as they were read?

Comment: what is this mess..? can you write real code for your inner foreach loop also if you are deleting a record how can you expect the list to be the same order..

Comment: The code is simply meant to give you an idea of what I am currently doing. it is simply Pseudocode. What I am really after is info on whether I am guaranteed to have the contents of my file processed the order it appears in the file this way.

Comment: if you want to insure that items are returned in order you can Sort on the List<> I would personally write real code then if you are having issues report back with your questions or concerns.. this will lead to less assumptions from others..

Comment: Why would I sort the list when all I want is to make sure it appears exactly in the order the lines appear in the original file?

Comment: @Kobojunkie It's likely that the error is somewhere in your actual code, so posting that would be very useful, if you want to get answer that actually fixes your code.

Comment: @Kobojunkie are you *actually seeing a problem* with this code not printing your records out in the correct order? Your comments make me wonder if this question is even on-topic: http://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask

Comment: There is no error. I am simply asking a question to understand if, based the pseudo-code logic, I am guaranteed to have my lines processed in order, no matter the information contained in the file, or how big or small the file is. I don't understand why some seem busy analyzing the correctness of the pseudo-code, rather than than the correctness of the logic contained.

Comment: @Kobojunkie It's not that we/they are analyzing your code or your logic. It's more like trying to figure out why you would post this on SO concerning a problem _that does not even exist_ instead of posting this on maybe codereview where it would be more appropriate.

Answer (score 2):

There's no method `File.ReadAll`.

The methods `File.ReadAllLines` and `File.ReadLines` already return the lines of the file in the correct order. So you don't need to do anything to assure that.

(The difference between them is that `File.ReadAllLines` reads the entire file into memory at once and gives you an array with the full file contents, while `File.ReadLines` is lazy and only reads from the file when you `foreach` through the returned object. In the last case you don't have to read all of the file, and the entire file will not have to be in memory at once, since you read "line by line".)

Answer (score 0):

nott 100% sure what you if statement is doing but why not use Linq

```
var lines = File.ReadAll(filepath)
                .Where(x=>( x.Something == "something else"));

File.WriteAll (lines, SecondPath)
```

or  in your case a more likely alternatively

```
var lines = File.ReadAll(filePath).Distinct();
```

this should keep the order in which the lines are read into a list.
Also you need to be careful when modifying the contents of an object during a foreach loop

Comment: Why Distinct()? What does Distinct() do for me in this case please?

Answer (score 0):

Unless you are explicitly sorting or reordering them somewhere, then you should already be seeing things happen in the order they appear in the file.

- The Framework objects which implement `IList` are inherently ordered
- `File.ReadAllLines` returns a list of lines in a text file in the order they appear.
- Enumerating over an `IList` using `foreach` accesses each element, in order.
- `File.WriteAllLines` writes the strings out, in order, to a new file.

Since the code you pasted wasn't actually the code you're using, it's impossible to see if you're doing something more subtle that is disrupting the order of elements in your input list. In particular, I'm very interesting in how you are doing the

`delete record`

part, since you *can't change the `IList` during enumeration*. My suspicion is, whatever you are doing to produce your second duplicate-free list is where your problem actually lies.

Comment: This is Pseudocode. As you can see, you cannot execute it as-is. I understand that I cannot delete from the Ilist while enumerating it. I am more interested in the order in which my file content will be processed here.

Comment: The second duplicate-free list is a copy of the first list really.